# Graphical effects are absent once Installing through Wubi

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

I'm using Dell Inspiron intel i5 chipset, 4GB RAM, 500GB hard drive with AMD graphics. I'm using windows 7 as my only OS earlier. Now I have installed 11.10 with help of Wubi. I have allocated 30GB space for Ubuntu. After installation it is working fine. But I could not get the 3D graphical effects as I expected.it is just functioning. Do I want to install as the only operating system to enjoy those graphical effects? Cann't I enjoy the same thing with wubi installation?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the "Additional Drivers" from menu or from the panel if appeared there and install the one which shown as "recommended".Reboot your ubuntu and you should be happy to see it working.